# Is there another way to change the return type of a static method of an abstract class based on the derived class type in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

**Edit:** The main purpose of this question is to gain a deeper understanding of C# and OOP in general. Please keep in mind that I'm not trying to solve a specific problem with this code, but instead just trying to understand how everything works.

I have a way to do this, but I'm wondering if there is another way to do it.

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{

    private const string ERROR = "Error";

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

    public static T Error<T>(string errorDescription)
        where T : ModelBase, new()
    {
        var model = new T
        {
            Status = ERROR,
            StatusDescription = errorDescription
        };
        return model;
    }

}
```

And then to call it:

```
return ModelBase.Error<ApplicationInit>("Failed to retrieve application segment.");
```

Where "ApplicationInit" is a derived class of ModelBase.

What would be super cool is if instead, I could call:

```
return ApplicationInit.Error("Failed to retrieve application segment.");
```

...And the code would be able to just tell what the derived class is.

IDK, maybe that's not possible...

Comment: Does this method need to be generic? You could create a private derived class of `ModelBase` and return that instead. `public static ModelBase Error(string errorDescription)`

Comment: There are _lots_ of alternatives, but which if any of those you'd consider suitable, there's no way to tell. The question is far too broad to be suitable for Stack Overflow. That said, what you have now seems like a reasonable "factory method" approach, and I fail to see how `ApplicationInit.Error` is in any material way preferable to `Error<ApplicationInit>`.

Comment: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern may work here. So you declare `class ModelBase<T> where T : ModelBase<T>` which looks really weird but works

Comment: Your second example, this "super cool way" can be achieved with [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 0):

No. When you declare a `static` method, there is only one version* of it. The call `ModelBase.Error<ApplicationInit>("")` and the call `ApplicationInit.Error<ApplicationInit>("")` will both compile to the exact same bytecode, and a good set of analyzers will flag the latter with a warning.

You can shadow `Error` with a new static method in `ApplicationInit`, but that would be a manual process for each new subclass. There is no way^ to generalize it more than you already have.

---

* A generic method can produce different bytecode for different type parameters, but all such methods are static members of `ModelBase`, and not any subclass.

^ You could write a source generator to generate these static methods, but that is a lot more work than just using the generic `ModelBase.Error<T>` method directly.